# How does an imageView appears in layers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KskM8.jpg)

I'm looking for help developing a UIImageView that appears like the imageviews in photo. It will include several images. I want it to be appears in layers.

Comment: Please describe better your problem and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're best off making a custom class (`UIView`) which accepts a few images. Then in that custom class, draw those images in `UIImageView`. Every time you're drawing that image make sure you're rotating the `UIImageView` a few degrees using `transform`. You could do something with a white border, too. This will intensify the 'polaroid photo' effect.